# Dataview doesn't get datagridview column header properly

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataview

Though I set a new column header in datatable before assigning it to datagridview, when I call this datagridview from dataview I get old column headers. Here is a part of my code:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
grid.DataSource = null;
ds.ReadXml(path);
var dt = ds.Tables[0];

dt.Columns["Name"].Caption = "Descr";
dt.Columns["Account"].Caption = "ACNT"; // I tried both .Caption and .Columname

grid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

I also tried changing column header after implementation of datagridview, but still without any result:

```
grid.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Descr";
```

How can I set a column header that later dataview can read it properly?

Comment: I also noticed that when I export my datagridview to csv excel file with StreamWriter it keeps old column headers  as well, as well as old  ordering. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the DataPropertyName, in your case:

```
dt.Columns["Name"].DataPropertyName = "Name";
dt.Columns["Name"].HeaderText = "Descr";

dt.Columns["Account"].DataPropertyName = "Account";
dt.Columns["Account"].HeaderText = "ACNT";
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution, but your method didn't help. I assigned DataPropertyName to datagridview columns as system gave me error when I applied it to datatable as you described. Still doesn't work.

Comment: @mlivme, I think you mean grid.Columns, not dt.Columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following below:

```
grid.DataSource = null;



        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {

                   ds.ReadXml(path);
                   var dt = ds.Tables[0];
                   sda.Fill(dt);

                   //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                   dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

                   //Set Columns Count
                   dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;

                   //Add Columns
                   dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "CustomerId";
                   dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Customer Id";
                   dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "CustomerID";

                   dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Contact Name";
                   dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Name";
                   dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "ContactName";

                   dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Country";
                   dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Country";
                   dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Country";
                   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
               }
           }
```

Another way,you could try with less lines of code. Use the Design view yourGrid->smart tag -> edited the column ->Data->DataProperty ->(Add your db column Name).

Once that is Done you can just call your grid.

```
   private void PopulateGrid()
        {
          
            grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
           
            List<Your table> yourTable_List = GetMethodOfTheData();
             var source = new BindingSource(yourTable_List , null);    
            grid.DataSource = source;

        }
```